# Notebook as production rest API

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, apache-zeppelin, data-science

I know databricks offers the possibility to simply convert **notebooks** into **"production-grade" rest APIs**.

Is there a similar functionality for open source notebooks like Zeppelin, Scala-Notebook or Jupiter Notebook or hue-notebook? It would be great if the solution would support sparkR.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Production-grade REST API ? Can you provide some references ?

Comment: well rather some useful API to quickly get the models into a production environment.

Comment: I am thinking about something like this: http://blog.ibmjstart.net/2016/01/28/jupyter-notebooks-as-restful-microservices/ maybe a bit more mature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for a Spark REST server solutions, like:

- https://github.com/cloudera/livy
- https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver

?

Comment: Yes and no. Currently we are working to implement our models using spark-jobserver. However, it does not "talk" R and still our notebooks need to be re-written. So some sort of automatic solution would be favourable.

Comment: Got it. Livy recently added R support, see https://github.com/cloudera/livy/pull/96
It might be only in master branch though.

Comment: I would prefer some integrated approach like https://www.lightbend.com/blog/scala-and-spark-notebook-the-next-generation-data-science-toolkit

Comment: do you know if livy is the only option which supports sparkR?

Comment: Yep, I think so.. You'll have to use Livy from master branch thought to have SparkR.